# MySQL Fill an Array String using Select

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I want to populate a string via MySQL, the string will be an Array.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","#######");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
$result = mysql_query("");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $saleArrayList = array("");

}
```

I want my Array like

```
  // $saleArrayList = array("data1seperatecomma,data2seperateacomma,etc,etc");
```

This is my new code:

```
$salesArrayList = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($salesArrayList, $row[0]);
}
$string = implode(',', $salesArrayList);
echo $string;
```

Works well!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to fill an array? Then use `array_push()` to add items to your array

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","#######");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
$result = mysql_query("");

$salesArrayList = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($salesArrayList, $row[0]);
}
```

If you want a string with comma delimiter based on an array you can use `implode()`:

```
$string = implode(',', $salesArrayList);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I updated my thread question at the top with the new code.